# Golang text highlighting support to Kate

Tags: go, debian, kate

How do I add golang text highlighting support to **Kate Editor** in Debian? I have the `go.xml` file stored in path `$GOROOT/misc/kate`. I can't figure out how to add the required highlights to my Kate installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put go.xml to

```
~/.kde/share/apps/katepart/syntax/ (user config)
```

or

```
/usr/share/kde4/apps/katepart/syntax/ (system config)
```

if this folder not exists, create it.

Comment: Some Linux distributions have ~/.kde4 instead of ~/.kde

Answer (score 0):

on my SUSE the path is:
$HOME/.kde4/share/apps/kate  (note: not katepart)
and I had to add the last "syntax" dir.